# AngularJs:Strange result in iterating key value pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array in angular as follows

```
$scope.arr={
    "abc/xyz/../": [
        "a1.txt",
        "a2.txt",
        "a3.txt"
    ],
    "": [
        "no-folder.txt"
    ],
    "abc1/xyz/../": [
        "a4.txt",
        "a5.txt",
        "a6.txt"
    ]
}
```

i want to iterate through this array and need to get the results as follows

```
    "a1.txt",
    "a2.txt",
    "a3.txt"
```

and

```
"no-folder.txt"
```

and

```
            "a4.txt",
            "a5.txt",
            "a6.txt"
```

i have tried  as follows

```
<div ng-repeat="test in arr track by $index">
    <h3 ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
        {{value}}
    </h3>
</div>
```

but i am getting strange results as each character is coming as result .
can u pleas help.

**update** 
please look to this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/771voyj6/8/

Comment: What's the output coming?

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: @NishamMahsin could you please create plunkr/jsfiddle ?

Comment: in js fiddle it is working properly https://jsfiddle.net/771voyj6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do but you can create your logic something like this it might work for you ,its some hardcoded work but change it accordingly

```
       $scope.test = []

       $scope.test.push(arr["abc1/xyz/../"]+arr[""]+arr["abc1/xyz/../"]);
```

Use test in ng-repeat .. :)

or you can do what i know with your code use ng-repeat like this for your code:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in arr">
            <div ng-repeat="test2 in test">
              {{test2}}
              </div>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: yes i have made this on fiddle let me send you the link   http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/75/

Comment: this is different from your answer! you are not using array push here.

Comment: :D :D :D  okay i have updated your fiddle please check this https://jsfiddle.net/771voyj6/11/

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the JSON you are getting is not valid JSON. In second second property of your object is `""`(blank) which would be invalid JSON.

**JSON**

```
{
    "abc/xyz/../": [
        "a1.txt",
        "a2.txt",
        "a3.txt"
    ],
    //in below line json has no key
    "": [
        "no-folder.txt"
    ],
    "abc1/xyz/../": [
        "a4.txt",
        "a5.txt",
        "a6.txt"
    ]
}
```

**Update**

Apology for having wrong conceptualization regarding JSON, above JSON is valid JSON (but technically JSON shouldn't have blank key). I tried the above code in Fiddle which is working fine.

[**Working Fiddle(Angular 1.4.8)**](https://jsfiddle.net/771voyj6/)

Comment: this array i am getting as a result. any possibility to solve this?

Comment: @NishamMahsin you must have getting invalid json related error in your console..did you checked it..

Comment: @i am not getting any error . am getting answer but as iterating  each character  as a,b,x,y,z,/,.,., etc..

Comment: @NishamMahsin could you look at the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/771voyj6/ its working correctly..

Comment: @yes it working in fiddle..but same thing i am using in program but not working

Comment: @NishamMahsin what is the version of angular you are using?

Comment: @NishamMahsin its not version related problem..the fiddle has same version..I don't know..you must have missed something else..

Comment: @NishamMahsin I don't understand, what you are doing over there..? are you creating json manually? I thought you were getting that JSON from ajax response from some API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97078/discussion-between-nisham-mahsin-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: yes i am getting from ajax only . but for fiddle i have done like this.

Comment: @NishamMahsin why you don't use variable to store the response..I don't really understood what you meant to say..

Comment: thanks mate.. i got the answer.. i have updated my answer.

Comment: @NishamMahsin thats really wiered part.. You could have accept/edit one of our answer instead of adding your own..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if Pankaj is right regarding the empty key value. But certainly your `$scope.arr` is not an array but an object.
As such your code should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value)in arr track by $index">
    <h3 ng-repeat=" item in value">
        {{item}}
    </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your HTML code with the following:

`<div ng-repeat="test in arr track by $index">
          <div ng-repeat="item in test">
            {{item}}
          </div>
 </div>`

I am getting the result. Please check the following JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/akonchady/a25r1mm4/3/

Comment: @NishamMahsin Did you see the jsfiddle ? I am getting the desired result of file names even after putting '#'.
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/akonchady/a25r1mm4/4/
Please check.

Comment: If it's working fine in the fiddle, it should work anywhere else too. You must be having some additional code in your program.